# Convergence/divergence series

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Determine whether the following is converging or diverging

$$\sum_{i=1}^∞ \frac{\sin(1/i)}{\sqrt{i}}$$

I tried the following, but not sure whether it's correct:

$$\frac{\sin(1/i)}{\sqrt i}$$ <= $$\frac {1}{n\sqrt n}$$

Hence by the nth term test, $$\frac {1}{n\sqrt n}$$ is convergent, hence the series converges

But I am not sure how to prove $$\frac{\sin(1/i)}{\sqrt i}$$ is less than or = to $$\frac {1}{n\sqrt n}$$

Comment: You do not need to *evaluate it* to prove it is a convergent series. The (asymptotic) comparison test and the p-test are enough.

Comment: I was in the process of making the same comment as Jack when I saw his.  So let me just elaborate: *evaluate* means *find the value of*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply note that

$$\frac{\sin(1/i)}{\sqrt{i}}\sim \frac{1}{i\sqrt{i}}$$

then the given series converges by [**limit comparison test**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/677042/505767) with $\sum \frac{1}{i\sqrt{i}}$.

Comment: may i understand how do you get that sin(1/i)/sqrt(i) <= 1/isqrt(i)?

Comment: @Isabella.T Since for $$\frac1i \to 0 \implies \sin\frac1i \sim \frac1i$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** Every term of your sum is non-negative. Use the inequality $\sin x\le x$ for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Can i check that the above series is divergent?

Comment: @Isabella.T No, your series is converges. (Why?)