# Determining whether the series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I was tasked with determining whether the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)   $$

converges.

I tried employing the integral test which failed and produced incalculable integrals. Other methods didn't prove effective also. I was suggested that the Maclauren series might be of use here, but I'm not sure how to employ it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or by [**limit comparison test**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/677042/505767) with $\sum\frac1n$ since by standard limit for $x\to 0\implies\frac{\tan x}{x}\to 1$ and then

$$\frac{\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac1n}\to1$$

Comment: That's an efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Bak1139 Yes indeed limit comparison test avoid to use inequalities which sometimes are difficult to handle.

Answer (score 4):

We can solve this with the inequality $\tan(x)>x$ for $0<x<\pi/2$ as follows
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$$
And you probably already know that the harmonic series diverges (it can be proven by integral test).

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Note that for any positive integer $n$,
$$\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)> \frac{1}{n}.$$
See [Why $x<\tan{x}$ while $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/why-x-tanx-while-0x-frac-pi2)

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\tan \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\sim_{_{\infty}} \frac{1}{n} $$
As
$$\tan \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}+O\left(n^{-3}\right)$$
Which can be derived from the Maclaurin series expansion of $\tan x$.