# Depending on the parameter $\alpha$ study the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\log(\log{n})}{\log^\alpha{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Depending on the parameter $\alpha$ study the convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\log(\log{n})}{\log^\alpha{n}}$$

So for $\alpha \gt 0$ and $x \gt 1$ the function $f(x)=\frac{\log(\log{x})}{\log^\alpha{x}}$ is decreasing so I can use the integral test

which is divergent for $\alpha =1$

Is my reasoning right? I don't know what to do next

Comment: How do you prove that the integral diverges?

Comment: I fixed it. I hope it's right

Comment: It seems uncorrect, try to derive to check. Cauchy condensation test would simplify a lot.

Comment: What is $\int u\,\mathrm{d}u$? It's not $\frac u2+C$. Even when that's fixed, what about $\alpha\ne1$?

Comment: Yes, I had my integral wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that eventually (notably for $n>e^e$)

$$\frac{\log(\log{n})}{\log^\alpha{n}}\ge \frac{1}{\log^\alpha{n}}$$

and for $\alpha>0$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\log^\alpha{n}}$$

diverges by [**limit comparison test**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/677042/505767) with $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1n$ indeed

$$\frac{\frac{1}{\log^\alpha{n}}}{\frac1n}=\frac{n}{\log^\alpha{n}}\to \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

For all $x\gt0$, $\log(x)\lt x$. Therefore, for all $x\gt1$ and $\alpha\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\log(x)^\alpha
&=\alpha^\alpha\log\!\left(x^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha\\
&\lt\alpha^\alpha x^{1/\alpha\cdot\alpha}\\[3pt]
&=\alpha^\alpha x
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, since $\log(\log(n))\ge1$ for $n\ge16$, it suffices to compare
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{\log(n)^\alpha}\ge\frac1{\alpha^\alpha}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1n
$$

Comment: Very nice and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

If you know Bertrand's series, the answer is obvious by the comparison test:

A *Bertrand's series* is a series
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^\alpha\,\log^\beta n}\qquad (\alpha,\beta\in\bf R)$$
and it is known to  converge if and only if

- either $\alpha>1$,
- or  $\alpha=1$ **and** $\beta>1$.

Comment: So is this right $\frac1{n^\alpha} \lt\frac1{\log^\alpha{n}} $, 

$\frac{\log(\log{n})}{n^\alpha} \lt\frac{\log(\log{n})}{\log^\alpha{n}} $,

$\frac1{n^\alpha{\log^{-1}(\log{n})}} \lt\frac{\log(\log{n})}{\log^\alpha{n}} $ 

so $\beta=-1$, therefore, the sequence diverges for $\alpha \lt 1$

Comment: It's much simpler than that: $\;\frac{\log\log n}{\log^\alpha n}>\frac1{\log^\alpha n}$ ($n>2$), and the latter series diverges.

Comment: yes for $\alpha \lt 1$

Comment: @J.Dane No, for every $\alpha$.